# WPF Binding Indexer type casting

Tags: c#, wpf

How to cast when Class's Indexer is returning System.Object ?

e.g. in C# we write as below, what will be equivalent in xaml for Binding this value?

(Home[6033] as Fridge)[100]

Comment: I think the answer you're looking for is an ItemsControl.  Although it depends what you want to do

Comment: `{Binding Home[6033][100]}` should work.

Comment: Or `{Binding Home[6033,100]}`, not sure.